# Unable to pip install pandas due to requirements

Tags: python

I`m trying to install pandas with pip,

```
pip install pandas
```

but I`m getting this error:

```
grpc-google-iam-v1 0.11.1 has requirement oauth2client<4.0.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
bittrex 0.1.4 has requirement requests==2.7.0, but you'll have requests 2.17.3 which is incompatible.
zipline 1.1.1 has requirement pandas<0.19,>=0.18.1, but you'll have pandas 0.23.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-speech-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 0.15.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-speech-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 0.15.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
networkx 2.0 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.90.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
```

when I try to downgrade oauth2client with

```
pip install oauth2client=4.0.0
```

I get this error:

```
grpc-google-iam-v1 0.11.1 has requirement oauth2client<4.0.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
bittrex 0.1.4 has requirement requests==2.7.0, but you'll have requests 2.17.3 which is incompatible.
zipline 1.1.1 has requirement pandas<0.19,>=0.18.1, but you'll have pandas 0.23.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-speech-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 0.15.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-speech-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 0.15.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
networkx 2.0 has requirement decorator>=4.1.0, but you'll have decorator 4.0.11 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 0.90.4 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
proto-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.0.0 which is incompatible.
```

How I fix this?

Comment: Do you need to have all the google-cloud stuff in the same environment?

Comment: No, I don't need it

Comment: The error message is telling you that the packages you currently have installed require oauth2client to be less than version 4.0.0. But pandas requires oauth2client version 4.0.0 or above. AFAIK, there is no clean way to do this. I think you can get fancy with `pkg_resources`. Alternatively, if you don't need both the proto-google libs and pandas at the same time, you could just have two different Python installs that you manage (would need to update PATH/PYTHONPATH to switch between them). Or just uninstall each proto-google lib.

Comment: Then I'd suggest uninstalling the google stuff, or installing Pandas in a clean virtualenv.

Comment: Which ones? I uninstalled oauth2client but the same message keeps appearing

Comment: I wouldn't uninstall anything, but rather create a new `python` environment using `anaconda`, and installing `pandas` there.